# Android: Can't get YouTube Player API work inside of a fragment

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get my app to play a YouTube video in a fragment, as [This Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) said that you can play YouTube videos in fragments.

But i can't get it done.

This is my code:

SingleArticleFragment:

```
public class SingleArticleFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    public static final String API_KEY = "my api key";
    public static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "_oEA18Y8gM0";
    // YouTube player view
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

    // Initializing video player with developer key
    youTubeView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

            // Hiding player controls
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), 1).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer";
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is article.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Cover Video -->
        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

        <!-- Article Cover Photo -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/single_article_cover_photo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight=".14"/>

        <!-- Article Title -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/single_article_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".14"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

LogCat Errors:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView

.
.
.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
```

So what LogCat is telling me: YouTube only works in Activities!, but android documentation says otherwise.

Can anybody help here please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You are mixing two different approaches**.

You can either use a [`YouTubePlayerView`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) together with a [`YouTubeBaseActivity`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeBaseActivity) or you can simply use a [`YouTubePlayerFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment)/[`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment). Using a `YouTubePlayerView` inside a `YouTubePlayerFragment` is simply wrong.

If you use the first approach (view + activity), you need to place the view in your XML and then set the `YouTubePlayer` to play inside that view.

If you use the second approach, you simply need to load the fragment in an appropriate container, initialize the `YouTubePlayer` and play the video.

---

**SOLUTION 1**

Remove the `YouTubePlayerView` from your XML and your code and replace it with a `FrameLayout` that will contain the `YouTubeSupportFragment`. Then, use a `ChildFragmentManager` to load the `YouTubeSupportFragment` inside that `FrameLayout`.

**SOLUTION 2**

Simply make your Activity extend the `YouTubeBaseActivity`, leave everything else as it is.

Comment: Obviously i need the second approach because it's a fragment, but what do you mean by `load the fragment in an appropriate container` ? 

And if i removed the YouTubePlayerView from my XML, where it will be shown ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate by placing the write code ?

Comment: You can put a `FrameLayout` in your layout and use that as a container for the `YouTubeSupportFragment`.

Comment: Ohh, ofcourse i have a FrameLayout in my MainActivity xml that loads fragments in it, but i didn't put it here because it's irrelevant.

Comment: I can't make my MainActivity extends `YouTubeBaseActivity` because it's extending `ActionBarActivity`, That's why i need the YouTube Player to work inside of a Fragment.

Comment: Then, use the first solution (which I updated as well).

Comment: I have only one Activity which is the MainActivty and everything else are Fragments. I'm using the NavigationDrawer

Comment: I'll try the first one, and get back to you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72851/discussion-between-fadi-obaji-and-dextor).

Comment: I choose second option but still video is not playing. giving me network error. Can someone please help me