# android : error inflating class YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-inflater

I want to integrate `YouTubeplayerView` in `RecyclerView` in Fragment.

I have downloaded and added `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar`in libs folder and updated `build.gradle` as `compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`.

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Header View -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlMessageHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_margin_padding_min">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/nivFromAvatar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_image_size"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_image"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tmp_logo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin_padding"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nivFromAvatar"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFromHeaderName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/str_from_header_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/message_header_name_text_size_max" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSentTimeStamp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/str_sent_timestamp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/message_header_name_text_size_min" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Content View -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llContentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvContentTextValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin_padding_min"
                android:text="@string/str_content_value"
                android:textSize="@dimen/message_header_name_text_size" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flItemCardNormalMedia"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nivContentImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/str_image" />

                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/ytpvItemCard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Action View -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llActionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/llActionNormal"
                layout="@layout/action_normal"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/llActionRatting"
                layout="@layout/action_rating"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

While I run the project, I get following error:

```
12-08 16:40:40.994 18436-18436/com.waysay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.waysay, PID: 18436
                                                            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Binary XML file line #79: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                at com.waysay.adapters.RecyclerAdapterMessage.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerAdapterMessage.java:48)
                                                                at com.waysay.adapters.RecyclerAdapterMessage.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerAdapterMessage.java:33)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5228)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4453)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl
```

If you want I can show you the code of `RecyclerViewAdapter` too..
Thanks..

Comment: Posting logcat error in code block is easier to read than in quote.

Comment: `Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012090/android-cant-get-youtube-player-api-work-inside-of-a-fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012090/android-cant-get-youtube-player-api-work-inside-of-a-fragment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView In List Adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570169/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-youtube-player-youtubeplayerview-in-lis)

Comment: @DamianKozlak Yea.. I know it.. But User had visitors had to scroll horizontally thats why I put in BlockQuote.. Anyways.. thanks.. :)